# count total amount of items only with php

Tags: php

How do I get the total amount of products I have selected using PHP, below is my code and `sum_total = 0` variable I have added to sum the total amount of products selected by my code but get different value as result.

```
<?php  
    // products
    $products = "";
    $sum_total = 0;

    $select_products = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY time_added DESC"; 
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $select_products);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // fetch results
        $product_id = $row["product_id"];
        $product_name = $row["name"];
        $product_amount = $row["amount"];

        // product img
        $select_product_img = "SELECT images FROM product_images WHERE for_product_id = ?"; 
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $select_product_img);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $product_id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $product_img);
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            // fetch results      
        }

        $products .= '
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
            <div class="single-product">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <a href="../product/'.$product_id.'">
                        <img class="default-img" src="../images/products/'.$product_img.'" alt="#">
                        <img class="hover-img" src="../images/products/'.$product_img.'" alt="#">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-content">
                    <h3><a href="../product/'.$product_id.'">'.$product_name.'</a></h3>
                    <div class="product-price">
                        <span>$'.number_format($product_amount).'</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
        
        // total amount of products
        echo $sum_total += $product_amount;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to accumulate a total for `$row["amount"]` or do you men you want to know how many products get selected? Its not really clear

Comment: now what you get in `$sum_total`?

Comment: To show the Total move the echo outside the loop! But leave the accumulation `$sum_total += $product_amount;` inside the loop

Comment: Unrelated to question but you could use a `join` (or left join if not all products have images) and combine the `product_images` query, so only 1 `select` is needed.

Comment: I want to get the total amount to all products selected @KUMAR

Comment: _Small Note_ There is little point in preparing a query that has no parameters. In that case a `->query()` will do fine

Comment: If more than 2 products are selected, I want to get the sum total of the 2 products. if product 1 is $10 and product 2 is $20, I want the sum total to be echo $30 @KUMAR

Comment: If more than 2 products are selected, I want to get the sum total of the 2 products. if product 1 is $10 and product 2 is $20, I want the sum total to be echo $30 @RiggsFolly

Comment: Your question should be titled ***count total amount of all items only with php*** currently it can be considered that you want to fetch row count, which is SQL task actually.

Comment: @aily why you make images table other not inserted into product?

Comment: @aily your problem is solved or not???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add $sum_total in your loop

```php
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // fetch results
        $product_id = $row["product_id"];
        $product_name = $row["name"];
        $product_amount = $row["amount"];
        $sum_total+=$row["amount"];
```

and echo just sum_total

```
echo $sum_total;
```

Comment: wow! thank u... I just added `$sum_total = 0` variable at the top and everything now works fine

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `$sum_total += $product_amount` within your loop and then only echo summed value

```php
<?php  
    // ...
    $sum_total = 0;
    // ...
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // ...
        $product_amount = $row["amount"];
        $sum_total += $product_amount;
        // ...    
    }
    // total amount of products
    echo $sum_total;
?>
```